# BigQuery: aggregate metrics by running 7d/14d/30d etc. buckets

Tags: google-bigquery

Anyone aware of a short, neat BQ query (#standardsql) to aggregate metrics (sessions / PVs / users etc.) by running 7d/14d/30d etc. buckets For ex.

16th-22nd April: 300K sessions
9th-15th April: 330K sessions
2nd-8th April: 270K sessions

OR, out-of-the box function that converts GA's date field (STRING) to days_since_epoch

I wrote a query but it's very complicated
- manually extract as YYY, MM, DD components with REGEXP_EXTRACT()
- convert to days_since_epoch using UNIX_DATE
- divide by '7' to group each row into weekly observations 
- use GROUP BY to aggregate & report

any pointers to simplify this use case will be highly appreciable !

Cheers!

Comment: Hard to type a real answer from my phone, but you can do this with a combination of `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` (for the sequences of dates) and `PARSE_DATE` to extract a DATE from the STRING column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone aware of a short, neat BQ query (#standardsql) to aggregate metrics (sessions / PVs / users etc.) by running 7d/14d/30d etc. buckets

See below 7d example for BigQuery Standard SQL - you can apply this logic to whatever data you have with hopefully light adjustments

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    day, CAST(1000 * RAND() AS INT64) AS events
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-01-01', '2017-04-25')) AS day
)
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE('%U', day) as week,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y, %B %d', MIN(day)) AS start, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y, %B %d', MAX(day)) AS finish,
  SUM(events) AS events
FROM data 
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week
```

It produces below output that can be used as a starting point for further tailoring to your desired  layout

```sql
week    start               finish              events   
01      2017, January 01    2017, January 07    3699     
02      2017, January 08    2017, January 14    4008     
03      2017, January 15    2017, January 21    3726    
...     ...                 ...                 ...
```

> OR, out-of-the box function that converts GA's date field (STRING) to days_since_epoch

To convert STRING expressed date into date of DATE type - use PARSE_DATE as in below example

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20170425') AS date
```

result is

```sql
date     
2017-04-25
```

> Finally, below is example/template for running 7d/14d/30d etc. buckets

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    DAY, CAST(1000 * RAND() AS INT64) AS events
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-01-01', '2017-04-25')) AS DAY
)
SELECT 
  DAY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN events END) AS days_07,
  SUM(CASE WHEN period = 14 THEN events END) AS days_14,
  SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30 THEN events END) AS days_30
FROM (
  SELECT
    dates.day AS DAY,
    periods.period AS period,
    SUM(events) AS events
  FROM data AS activity
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DAY FROM data GROUP BY DAY) AS dates
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT period FROM (SELECT 7 AS period UNION ALL 
                SELECT 14 AS period UNION ALL SELECT 30 AS period)) AS periods
  WHERE dates.day >= activity.day 
  AND CAST(DATE_DIFF(dates.day, activity.day, DAY) / periods.period AS INT64) = 0
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY DAY
ORDER BY DAY DESC
```

with output as below

```sql
DAY         days_07 days_14 days_30  
2017-04-25     2087    4004    9700  
2017-04-24     1947    4165    9611  
2017-04-23     1666    4066    9599  
2017-04-22     2121    4820   10014  
2017-04-21     2885    5421   10192
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikhail-berlyant for quick response. It definitely helped a lot, I wasn't aware PARSE_DATE could take 'YYYYMMDD' date_string as well (which btw I notice only works for %Y%m%d' forma string?!). Google doc only mention MM/DD/YY date_string format.

Comment: Just did, It definitely helped a lot, 

BTW I wasn't aware PARSE_DATE could take 'YYYYMMDD' date_string as well (which btw I notice only works for %Y%m%d' forma string?!). Google doc only mention MM/DD/YY date_string format.

Also I guess, on an edge case, it will break if we pull data >1 years, cause week numbers will repeated (that’s why I though of converting to days_form_epoch > divide by 7 > tale the integer portion as proxy for week #

Nonetheless, it more or less love our purpose. Thanks again !

Comment: Also, when you will post new question  - consider your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).